# Issue Running PhantomJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I'm currently running Windows 8 64 bit. No matter what version of PhantomJs I install, I get this error upon start up:

```
PhantomJs is a headless Webkit with Javascript API has stopped working.
```

What could the issue be? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what versions have you tried and from what download links?

Comment: I downloaded from PhantomJs.org

Comment: I tried 1.9.2, 1.9.1, and 1.9.0